# find the string(word) that appears more times

Tags: c

i have to give a a number x, and write x strings(words).
and i have to find the one that is writen most times.
it works but when i try to read it from file it doesn't.
for example if i do a.out''<'file and file is like :

1. 5
2. hello
3. yes
4. world
5. hello
6. ok

all of them in different lines, each string at different line it works and i print hello,but if a lot of strings are in one line like a text it wont work(hello yes word hello e.t.c...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char **str;
    int n,i,j,y;
    int count=0;
    printf("Give a nubmer : \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    str = (char **)malloc(n *(sizeof(50)));
    for(i=0; i<n+1; i++)
            str[i] = (char *)malloc(50);
    printf("Give n strings : \n");
    for(i=0; i<n+1; i++)
    {
            gets(str[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n+1; i++)
    {
            for (j=i+1;j<n+1;j++)
            {
                    if(strcmp(str[i],str[j])==0)
                    {
                            count++;
                    //      i++;
                            y=i;
                    }
            }
    }
    printf("\n%s\n",str[y]);
}
```

is it the prob that i use gets instead of fgets?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing related to reading from a file in your code.

Comment: @BrianRoach Maybe redirection?

Comment: sorry edited i use a.out '<' file.txt

Comment: gets() is deprecated.  Never use it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck If he uses it, will we need to rough him up? ;-)

Comment: @FiddlingBits: No, you just have to make sure his file contains 'supercalifragilistexpialidociously-antidisestablishmentarianistically' and 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch'.

Comment: Note that the loop `for(i=0; i<n+1; i++)` steps out of bounds of the array `str`; you allocated 50 strings and you try to use the 51st, which is not a recipe for happiness.  Making people count is the sort of nasty trick CS teachers do until people know how to allocate space dynamically.  Don't make the user count; read until EOF.

Comment: OP says "if a lot of strings are in one line like a text it wont work" and `gets()` reads a line at a time.  If you want to separate a line of text like "hello yes word hello" into "hello", "yes",  "word",  "hello", you will need to read them one word at a time or parse the line of text.

Comment: i use n+1 because if i give for example the number 4, i will be able to write 3 words and not 4.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
#define NUM_STRINGS (10)

int strListCompare(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const char **str1 = p1;
    const char **str2 = p2;
    return strcmp(*str1, *str2);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *strList[NUM_STRINGS] = {
                                     "dog", "cat", "cat", "bat", "cat", 
                                     "cat", "dog", "bat", "dog", "bat"
                                 };

    qsort(strList, NUM_STRINGS, sizeof(char *), strListCompare);

    char *curStr = strList[0], *maxStr = strList[0];
    int curCount = 0, maxCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < (NUM_STRINGS - 1); i++)
    {
        curCount++;

        if((strcmp(strList[i], strList[i + 1]) != 0) && (curCount > maxCount))
        {
            maxCount = curCount;
            maxStr = strList[i];
            curCount = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("The winner! \"%s\" (%d occurrences)\n", maxStr, maxCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing the above program results in the following output:

> The winner! "cat" (4 occurrences)

This is the logic:

> At first, `strList` is not sorted.  I sort it to aid in determining the string that occurs the most.  Before I scan `strList`, I assume the first element will be the most occurring string.  Now, I scan `strList` and count occurrences.  If the next string is the same as the current string, I increment `curCount`.  As soon as the next string is not the same as the current string, I compare `curCount` to `maxCount`.  If `curCount` is greater than `maxCount`, I've found a new string that occurs the most often.  I set `curCount` and the current string to `maxCount` and `maxStr` respectively.  When the loop ends, `maxCount` and `maxStr` will the have the string that occurs the most.

Comment: yea i see, but the prob i have is that if i get input file with a.out < file.txt and each string are in different line, my program works and i print the word that appears more times. but if in 1 line there are a lot of strings it doesn't. that's the prob.